# Word for feeling of closure or peace of a relationship (usually a bad one)

Tags: single-word-requests

As written in the title, there's a specific word that is not *too* common in English that's used to describe the feeling you can get when you finally resolve your long-term disdain for someone, or reaching some sort of civility between you and them.

I can't remember it but I would know it if I saw it.

Example:

> > He attained [a feeling of] ____ after talking to his estranged father after many years.

I'm not looking for synonyms of peace or closure, and nothing on Thesaurus.com has helped me. It is a very specific, unique word. It's like closure, peace of mind, or inner peace, but I've only seen it used in the context of sunsetting a toxic, detached relationship.

**Edit:**

The *actual* meaning of the word I was looking for was peace of mind for *any* period of negativity. It's not necessarily unique to interpersonal relationships.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps, **catharsis** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catharsis)

> 2b :  a purification or purgation that brings about spiritual renewal or release from tension

*"She has learned to have her catharsis, take a deep breath and move on. … she does not dwell on the negative anymore."* —Selena Roberts, New York Times, 24 June 2001

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharsis) explains in detail:

> [Stages of social catharsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharsis#Stages_of_social_catharsis):
>
> 1. Directly after emotional effects, the emotions are shared. Through sharing, there is a reciprocal stimulation of emotions and emotional communion.
> 2. This leads to social effects like social integration and strengthening of beliefs.
> 3. Finally, individuals experience a renewed trust in life, strength, and self-confidence

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible words which can be used in such scenarios-

1.**Detachment**

2.**Equanimity** - is a state of psychological stability and composure which is undisturbed by experience of or exposure to emotions, pain, or other phenomena that may cause others to lose the balance of their mind.

There is one more beautiful word synonymous to peace- **Serenity**, which is perfect for such situations.

Answer (score 1):

The word in which I was looking for would be closure.

Comment: Yep.  Even though the word's in the question's title, it's likely been (unfairly) passed over by OP.

Comment: Are you answering the question or stating you have the same problem?